# Fatal error with mysqli_stmt::get_result() out of sync error

Tags: php, mysql, get

when I try this

```
    $sql = "SELECT t.fb_fullname,
        s.wins, 
        s.points FROM favorits_tbl AS f 
          INNER JOIN fb_tbl AS t ON f.favorit_id = t.user_id 
            INNER JOIN score_tbl AS s ON f.favorit_id = s.user_id 
        WHERE f.user_id = ?";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user_id);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    }
```

I got an

```
    Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

error.

What's wrong?
I'm using PHP 5.6 and the mysqlnd driver.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: Try this: $stmt->bind_param(1, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: We would need to see more code. Basically you have not consumed all of the previous database access resultset